# Why URDF-related error raises when loading XML mujoco file in pybullet?

Tags: xml, pybullet, mujoco, urdf

I'm trying to import xml file in pybullet which has no problem on loading in mujoco.

Error message is that

```
b3Printf: b3Warning[examples/SharedMemory/PhysicsServerCommandProcessor.cpp,3584]:

b3Printf: URDF file with multiple root links found
```

Even though not using URDF, why is this error raised, and how can it be fixed?

Test file in mujoco. Worked well.

Comment: To get an answer, you should probably include the actual failing XML and the Python code you use to load it.

Comment: @NimrodGilead
- used https://github.com/osudrl/cassie-mujoco-sim/blob/master/model/cassie.xml
- load xml by code

p.loadMJCF("/Users/pybullet/cassie-mujoco-sim/model/cassie.xml")[0]

Comment: two warings are :
b3Printf: /Users/pybullet/cassie-mujoco-sim/model/cassie.xml:84: joint without axis attribute
b3Printf: URDF file with multiple root links found

Comments:
I think first error code is because when loading XML in pybullet, it checks the XML code line by line whether every attrbitues including 'axis' is included in 'joint'. It is fixed simply adding axis attributes. But in this case, itsnot correct representation for multiaxis case e.g. ball joint.

-Basic problem is that the loading cassie XML file isn't working well. Also its weird to raise URDF-related (2nd) warning.